# How to plot two half polar charts beside each other

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am attempting to plot two half polar charts beside each other using matplotlib, pandas and numpy. The plots are calles c30 and c31. c31 plots well on its own but c30 does not, it appears as a line as you can see in the picture. Also they sit on top of each other instead of side by side. Can anyone advise on how to solve this problem?

What I currently achieve:
[image: What I currently achieve]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
c31df = pd.DataFrame({'measure':[0,7.52,7.91,8.57,8.9,8.94,9.36,9.21,7.97,6],      'angle':[0,52,60,75,90,110,120,135,150,180]})
c30df = pd.DataFrame({'measure':[0,5.1,7.26,7.58,8.1,8.46,8.51,8.9,8.94,7.87],  'angle':[0,52,60,75,90,110,120,135,150,180]})
c31x=c31df.measure[:-1] * np.cos(c31df.angle[:-1]/180*np.pi)
c31y=c31df.measure[:-1] * np.sin(c31df.angle[:-1]/180*np.pi)
c30x=c30df.measure[:-1] * np.sin(c30df.angle[:-1]/180*np.pi)
c30y=c30df.measure[:-1] * np.sin(c30df.angle[:-1]/180*np.pi)
c31x = np.r_[c31x, c31x[0]]
c31y = np.r_[c31y, c31y[0]]
c30x = np.r_[c30x, c30x[0]]
c30y = np.r_[c30y, c30y[0]]
# noinspection PyTupleAssignmentBalance
c31tck, c31u = interpolate.splprep([c31x, c31y], s=0, per=True)
c31xi, c31yi = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0,1,1000), c31tck)
# noinspection PyTupleAssignmentBalance
c30tck, c30u = interpolate.splprep([c30x, c30y], s=0, per=True)
c30xi, c30yi = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0,1,1000), c30tck)
def cart2pol(x,y):
    rho = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(y,x)
    return(rho, phi)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
c31ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
c31ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
c31ax.set_theta_direction(1)
c31ax.set_thetamax(180)
c31ax.plot(cart2pol(c31xi, c31yi)[1], cart2pol(c31xi, c31yi)[0], linewidth=1,      linestyle='solid', color='red', label='Chart')
c30ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
c30ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
c30ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
c30ax.set_thetamax(180)
c30ax.plot(cart2pol(c30xi, c30yi)[1], cart2pol(c30xi, c30yi)[0], linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', color='green', label='Chart')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I have tried moving theta position around, and it changed the graph but still sat in the wrong position.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```py
c30x=c30df.measure[:-1] * np.sin(c30df.angle[:-1]/180*np.pi)
```

to this:

```py
c30x=c30df.measure[:-1] * np.cos(c30df.angle[:-1]/180*np.pi)
```

When you use `add_subplot()`, you need to provide the expected layout and where your subplot will fit in that layout. One of the ways is to call it as `add_subplot(nrows, nlins, pos)`.

In your case, you want one row and two columns, therefore:

```py
c31ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='polar')
c30ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='polar')
```